# What is the equivalence for QString::arg() in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qstring

I'm wondering How I can have a string in QML that will be occupied with some arguments? Some thing like this in Qt:

```
QString str("%1 %2");
str = str.arg("Number").arg(12);//str = "Number 12"
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In QML environment, the arg() function already added to the string prototype, so basically you can use the string.arg() in QML just like C++.

There is less documentation about this, but I'm sure it works in Qt 4.7 + QtQuick 1.1

Take at look at the Qt 5 doc : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qml-string.html

Answer (score 23):

just use :

```
"foo%1".arg("bar");
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want multiple argument replacements:

```
"foo%1 bar%2".arg("bar").arg("foo");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
property string str1: "Foo"
property string str2: `${str1}/Bar` // here will "Foo/Bar" as result
```

Answer (score -2):

You might be able to do this with a jQuery plugin:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/jQuery.format

```
import "jQuery.js" as JQuery

    Page {

        property string labelStub: "hello {0}"

        Label {
            text: JQuery.validator.format(labelStub, "world")
        }
     }
```

Answer (score -4):

Arguments are totally unnecessary in this example. In JS, we have simple string concatenation which also supports numbers in between, so you can achieve this with a simple

```
var str = 'Number' + ' ' + 12
```

If you really want arguments in non-literal strings, you can just replace the `%1` with the replacement. `QString::arg` (with one argument) is nothing more than the following:

```
function stringArg(str, arg)
{
    for(var i = 1; i <= 9; ++i)
        if(str.indexOf('%'+i) !== -1)
            return str.replace('%'+i, arg);
    return str;
}
```

So your code becomes:

```
var str = "%1 %2"
str = stringArg(str, "Number")
str = stringArg(str, 12)
```

(Note that this function can only handle `%1`..`%9`, while `QString::arg` can handle up to `%99`. This requires a bit more logic, since `%10` is teated as a `%1` in my code. So this is not exactly the same as `QString::arg`, but it will suffice in the most cases. You could also write a `stringArg` function taking multiple replacement arguments, but for the simplicity I just wrote this one here.)

Comment: This "simple" string concatenation has far too internal conversions, that are also rather inconsistent.

Comment: This results in untranslatable applications. Not a great idea.

Comment: This is not usefull for translations purpose. Sometimes the order of words need to be changed in translation to other language