# Joining 2 strings in QML

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I set property of qml using C++ function (from library, I do not see implementation), after use of this function property
on button is changed as expected (value which I set from c++ code), but on text is set just "My name is:" without value. My question is, how to join two strings 
in QML javascript function when one is result of **qsTr()** function and second is **property** set from C++?

```
property string name: ""

function myFunction() {
   myText.text = qsTr("My Name is: ") + name;
   //myText.text = qsTr("My Name is: " + name);//another try
}
Text{
    id: myText
    text: ""
}
Button {
    text: name
}
```

On Button: `John Smith`

On Text: `My Name is:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalence for QString::arg() in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758282/what-is-the-equivalence-for-qstringarg-in-qml)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not joining strings, it's the binding.

When you are doing `myText.text = ...` `name` is not yet set. And since you are doing an imperative assignation, it won't be updated if `name` changes.

You could maintain a binding with [`Qt.binding()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#binding-method):

```
myText.text = Qt.binding(function() {return qsTr("My Name is: ") + name;});
```

Or alternatively, you could just do it declaratively in `myText`:

```
Text {
    id: myText
    text: qsTr("My Name is: ") + name
}
```

More information here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with args

```
var message = "My name is %1";
var name = "John Smith";
myText.text = message.arg(name);
```